# Furnace reaches temp, shuts off but wont come back on

Tags: electrical, switch, furnace, thermostat, natural-gas

I have an American Standard furnace (natural gas)with a manufacture date of 2004.

The thing won't come on unless I power it off (have a switch right beside it that serves this purpose), let the fan stop spinning, open and close the kill switch, then power it on again....and it will run just fine until it hits set temperature then goes off as it should.

Then if I want to call for heat again I have to go through the entire process again.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is the "*kill switch*"? Is that the servicemen switch next to the unit?

Comment: If the unit has a variable fan delay, what is the fan off delay set to?

Comment: When is the last time you changed the filter?

Comment: The kill switch is on the unit itself and is depressed while the cover is on..when the cover is removed it disengages and kills power to the unit.

Comment: Don't see any variable fan delay.

Comment: The model # is AUD120R954K5 and is an American Standard. The filter was changed yesterday.

Comment: Does the unit have a pilot light, or electronic ignition? How often was the filter changed?

Comment: Hi Darren I’m having the same problem with mine did you ever find out what the problem was?!

Comment: Sounds like a safety measure to consumers for carbon poisoning, check your limit switches, any clogs in the inducer lines ? Most likely your high limit switch, they sit all around the burner, on the back and on the front to detect the flame to protect the homeowner

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a safety lockout occurring on shutdown.  You are probably clearing the lockout each time you go through your procedure.

Look for a failure code to be set on the control board after the furnace stops.  The code should point you in the correct direction.